# How to re-install Ubuntu 14.04 with 14.04 CD?

Tags: system-installation

I want to reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 (for various reasons) but when I put the CD in it doesn't give me that option. How do I get the option to reinstall? I want to keep my home drive the same.
At the moment I get the options to:

Install on same hdd with different partitions.

Install by formatting hdd.

Comment: so back up your file restore after fresh install , where is the issue

Comment: I *think* you could install to the same partition, but make sure to uncheck the "format" option.  It would not be ideal, as it would keep possible unused files around.  Best to copy /home to another partition, then either keep it that way, or copy back.  Also, best to back up /home anyway.

Comment: What options do you get?